Intuition on geometry of sections
Premise: I have asked the same question on math.stackexchange about a week ago, without receiving answer. Therefore I've decided to ask it also here. If this violates the rules, I apologize and I'll delete this question.
We work over ${\mathbb C}$. Let $Y$ be a smooth projective variety, and let $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ over $Y$. Define $X:= \mathbb{P}_Y(\mathcal{E})$ to be the projective bundle over $Y$ (following Hartshorne's book notation), with projection map $\pi:X\to Y$.
I know that sections $s:Y\to X$ of $\pi$ are in correspondence with quotient invertible sheaves $\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{L}\to 0$. This suggests me that the quotient invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ tells something about the image of section $s$, and I would like to understand it with explicit examples.
For instance, suppose I have that I have the following quotients:

$\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{O}_Y\to 0$
$\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{O}_Y(1)\to 0$
$\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{O}_Y(-1)\to 0$

Thanks to Harthsorne, chap. II, exercise 7.8, I know that I obtain sections $s: Y\to X$ such that, in each of the above quotients, we get that:

$s^*\mathcal{O}_{X}(1)=\mathcal{O}_Y$
$s^*\mathcal{O}_X(1)=\mathcal{O}_Y(1)$
$s^*\mathcal{O}_X(1)=\mathcal{O}_Y(-1)$

I would expect that these quotients give rise to different sections. Is there a way to understand the geometry of the associated sections? For instance, am I contracting the image of the section? Is it isomorphic to $Y$?

Of course, $\pi $ induces an isomorphism of $s(Y)$ onto $X$. And I don't understand what you mean by "am I contracting the image of the section?".

Dear @abx, thank you very much for your answer. I guess I am quite confused about all of this, I thought the sections do not need to be isomorphic to $Y$, and my guess was that we constructed the section as the projective spectra of the section rings $\bigoplus_{m\geq 0} H^0(Y,ms^*\mathcal{O}_Y(1))$ (and in case 1., this was the meaning of "we contract the section")

But for instance, consider a cone $X=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ over a smooth projective variety $Y$, which has a structure of $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $Y$. I thought that I could construct a section $s: Y\to X$ such that $s(Y)$ was the vertex of the cone, and such section was determined by a quotient of the vector bundle $\mathcal{E}\to L\to 0$.

I don't understand what you say. $X$ is not a cone.
